# Can´t style Snapshot theme from WooThemes´s child theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I´ve created a child theme of the Snapshot theme from WooThemes.

But it seems I´m not succeeding to style the child theme.

Here´s the style.css header/code of the child theme:

```
/*
Theme Name: My Child Theme
Theme URI: http: //kevingstongramado.p.ht/
Description: This is a custom child theme I have created.
Author: Marcelo Noronha
Template: snapshot
Version: 1.0
*/

@import url("../snasphot/style.css");

div#temp{
color:#00FF00;
}
```

I´ve pressed F12 in Chrome, to see what could be.
The 'style.css' file, that appears, is the 'style.css' from the parent theme.
I don´t know if it shouldn´t has loaded the 'style.css' from the child.

I´ve a directory, 'snapshot', for the parent, and 'snapshot-child', for the child theme.

I have activated the child theme.

Can´t seem to find the 'style.css' file of the child theme, using F12 in Chrome.

The URL of the site is http://kevingstongramado.p.ht/

The text that should be styled in the page, is 'Test2'.

EDIT:

I´ve used FireBug in FireFox. Also, the site doesn´t seems to have loaded the 'style.css' from child theme.

Anyone?

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not as an anonymous (suggested) edit to the question. For now, I've quoted the answer, but if it's yours, you should post it - then I'll delete my quote of it. Did you forget to log in?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from an anonymous user, found in the edit review queue:

---

I don´t know, but it seems that in this theme, you can´t add styles in the 'style.css' child theme file.

I´ve tried to make some changes in the header.php, using one of the answers from this forum.

Like:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() 
?>/style.css" />
```

But it completly screwd up layout.

So I realized, using FireBug, that the stylesheet that is loaded from the child theme, is the file "custom.css".

So that is the answer. Using the child theme file, "custom.css", you can add styles to your child theme.